# How does one store an image in MySQL with a link to the photo in Amazon S3?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, alamofire

So let's say I want to upload a photo to Instagram on iOS using the Alamofire framework to upload it to my server.

```
Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    "http://sample.com/api/upload",
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, 
                                     name: "yourParamName", 
                                     fileName: "imageFileName.jpg", 
                                     mimeType: "image/jpeg")
```

Here's the problem: how does the `"imageFileName.jpg"` get converted into an identifier unique enough to find within thousands of users' pictures in Amazon S3?

Here would be db table of what I mean:

```
ID | USERNAME | PHOTO
_____________________
1  |   ROCKY  | <AWS S3 PHOTO URL GOES HERE??>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use username and date/time combo as prefix for s3, creating a unique S3 name.
Say for Rocky uploading an image **image.jpg** today, the s3 url could be

```
s3://your-bucket/Rocky/Dec23image.jpg
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion! I was thinking of hashing the image name, which, would also be a good idea (as long as collisions don't happen).

Comment: Yep ..your choice. Just remember if s3 url of a new upload is same as an existing one , it will be overwritten